# How can I locate all occurrences of model files with the name sfunction_name?

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

i am using waijung blockset to programm a stmµc. And i wanted to use CAN-Bus blocks but i am facing the following error:

The build process will terminate as a result.
Caused by:
Error, a block diagram was specified in S-function 'stm32f4_can/CAN Setup'. Please make sure your S-function name is not a Simulink model or the name of the current model. You can use the Matlab command 'which -all sfunction_name' to locate all occurrences of model files with the name sfunction_name

hereby i did not insatll MinGW-w64 C/C++ compiler yet. I also tried in comand window >> which -all sfunction_name
'sfunction_name' not found.

[image: Error]

Comment: Just to be clear, you are typing the name of the problematic S-Function --  which in your case seems to be `CAN1_Setup` -- and **not** literally typing `sfunction_name`, aren't you?

Comment: unfortunately i do not understand u

Comment: The message is telling you to type `which -all CAN1_Setup` **not** `which -all sfunction_name`.  (Assuming that the name of the problematic function is `CAN1_Setup`.)

Comment: thank yout i tried it but did not help    >> which -all CAN1_Setup
'CAN1_Setup' not found.

Comment: Then check the name of the S-Function that the block called `Can Setup` (in your image) is trying to use.